# android HTTP request fail

Tags: java, android, web-services, http

I wrote an Android application that communicates with a webserver(wampserver and php) using the class `AsyncTask` here is its code:

```
 public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d("", "onPreExecute: ");
    }
    @Override
    protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("", "doInBackground: ");
        try {
            String NewsData;
            //define the url we have to connect with
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            //make connect with url and send request
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //waiting for 7000ms for response
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(7000);//set timeout to 5 seconds

            try {
                //getting the response data
   /*Line : 117*/InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                //convert the stream to string
                NewsData = ConvertInputToStringNoChange(in);
                //send to display data
                publishProgress(NewsData);
            } finally {
                //end connection
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

        }catch (Exception ex){}
        return null;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

        try {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),progress[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("PROGRESS ??", progress[0]);
            //response = progress[0];
            alertDialog.setMessage(progress[0]);
            alertDialog.show();
            response = true;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String  result2){
        response = true;
    }
}
public static String ConvertInputToStringNoChange(InputStream inputStream) {

    BufferedReader bureader=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line ;
    String linereultcal="";

    try{
        while((line=bureader.readLine())!=null) {
            linereultcal+=line;
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){}

    return linereultcal;
}
```

I used this class as an inner class in `LoginActivity` which, upon pressing the button: `authButton`, gets the email and password from the user, passes them to the server with GET method, verifies the existence of the user in the database, and if it exists it returns the username, else it returns "wrong login check again"

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private TextInputEditText mPasswordView;
private Button authBtn;
private String email;
private String password;
private boolean response = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPasswordView = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    authBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    authBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            email = mEmailView.getText().toString().trim();
            password = mPasswordView.getText().toString().trim();
            if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
             //blah blah blah
            } else {
                String urlString = "http://localhost/webapp/login.php?email="+email+"&user_pass="+password;
                LoginTask logintask = new LoginTask();
                logintask.execute(urlString);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I run the app on my phone (samsung S4 Andoid 5.0.1 API 21) it appears to execute this statement:

```
 LoginTask logintask = new LoginTask();
```

But, there is no trace of it and no result. Even the `Log.d()` in the different methods of `LoginTask` are not displayed in Logcat. Instead, this is what I get in Logcat when pressing the `authButton` :

```
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
(HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
(HTTPLog)-Thread-14638-1006967439: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
```

this is the declaration code for publishProgress() :

```
@WorkerThread
protected final void publishProgress(Progress... values) {
    if (!isCancelled()) {
        getHandler().obtainMessage(MESSAGE_POST_PROGRESS,
                new AsyncTaskResult<Progress>(this, values)).sendToTarget();
    }
}
```

As for the Login.php, I tested it and it gives proper results, no problem there.

After adding `printStackTrace()`, this is the message displayed in the log

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.10/webapp/login.php?email=example.example@gmail.com&user_pass=azerty
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
W/System.err:     at com.ghazelatc.karim.monboutique.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:117)
W/System.err:     at com.ghazelatc.karim.monboutique.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:94)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: You need to provide your server's IP instead of localhost

Comment: I'm using a localhost server in WampServer. How do I get the server IP ?

Comment: In one of your comments you do mention using server IP. Just to be sure can you access your wamp server via mobile browser? Both should be on same network and wamp must be allowing connections from outside.

Comment: I see, I tried to access the server from the phone navigator using the server IP, but it appears it's not allowed, it mainly displays : **Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server**.
(Both PC and phone connected to the same network)
This must be my problem, how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue is that your wamp server is denying the connection, since that is the default behavior.

You can go to `httpd.conf` config file. Then look for a section that starts with the `Directory` tag. You can add `Allow from all` for a quick test but that is a big security no-no.

So you need to do `Allow from 192.168.0.0`, assuming `192.168.0.0` is your network address.

The specific syntax depends on your wamp server but this should get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the variable?

```
NewsData = ConvertInputToStringNoChange(in);
```

Where is this function declaration?

```
publishProgress(NewsData);
```

You aren't returning anything in doBackground() function.

Comment: ConvertInputToStringNoChange() is declared at the end of LoginTask code, check the last lines in the first code segment.

Comment: publishProgress() is a pre-defined method declared in AsyncTask. it supposedly returns the result of doInBackround() to onProgressUpdate(). I added the declaration code to the post.

Comment: You don't need to use this method. Use onProgressUpdate during progress and OnPostUpdate at the process finish. Avoid use thread objects into AsyncTask objects.
Other thing: the content of NewsData should be returned in doInBackground to be recovered in OnPostUpdate where You can update your screen.

Comment: I returned NewsData in doInBackround and added the treatements in onPostExecute :
protected void onPostExecute(String  result){
            if( result!=null && !result.equals("wrong login check again"))
            {
                Log.d("onPostExecute RESULT : ", "good result");
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",result);
                intent.putExtra("mail",email);
                startActivity(intent);
          }
            else{
                Log.d("onPostExecute RESULT : ", result);} }

Comment: and "result" is always null

Comment: It turns out that the Apache server's not allowing any outside device to send requests to the server, I tried from another computer and my phone to access the server via browser, but it displays I don't have sever access permission. I didnt solve this yet, but now I'm sure the problem isn't in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what is exactly happening.
However it may be helpful to you to treat the exception in that try-catch block. At the moment you're letting exceptions fall silently.

```
   try {

    }catch (Exception ex){}
    return null;
}
```

Change that over to:

```
   try {
    ....
    }catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Maybe you'll get some feedback with that.
Just double checking you got the android.permission.INTERNET" permission in your manifest?

Also, try using network IP instead of localhost.

Comment: I did as you said. And there is an exception :

Comment: Is 192.168.1.10 the IP of your server in your LAN?

Comment: its the pc ipv4 ip address : command prompt --> ipconfig--> ipv4 address